# Dynamically setting git config in python

Tags: python, python-gitlab

In my python program, I am trying to dynamically set user credentials - GIT config for GIT.

Repo.config_writer().set_value("user", "name", "username").release()
Repo.config_writer().set_value("user", "email", "email@domain.com").release()

It is giving error,
TypeError: config_writer() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

git.Git(path).clone(gitlab_url) - Clone is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the name of the variables count so much, but you could try (taking into consideration that you've put you data in variables, not directly into the set_value() method):

```
repo.config_writer().set_value("user", "name", "myusername").release()
repo.config_writer().set_value("user", "email", "myemail").release()
```

If this one doesn't work, a workaround could be :

```
os.system("git config --global user.name \"firstname lastname\"")
os.system("git config --global user.email \"youremail@email.com\"")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I got following error on trying repo.config_writer -> AttributeError: module 'git.repo' has no attribute 'config_writer